# Returning Max Date and Null Date From Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to achieve results of a max date or a null date for a specific time period from a joined table. Is the issue with the join or my having clause?  I'm at a loss right now.

I've checked numerous questions on StackOverflow, and I haven't been able to achieve the desired outcome reporting the null results as well as the max results.

```
SELECT 
i.item
, i.description
--, i.last_inv
--, i.change_date
, CASE WHEN MAX(case when m.trans_date is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN MAX(m.trans_date) END AS 'last_used'
FROM item_mst i
LEFT JOIN matltran_mst m on m.item = i.item
WHERE i.item like '2%' and m.trans_type <> 'M'   
GROUP BY i.item, i.description
HAVING (MAX(m.trans_date) NOT BETWEEN '10/1/2017' and '5/8/2019' or MAX(m.trans_date) IS NULL) 
ORDER BY 'last_used'
```

I'm expecting about 8 results with a last_used date and over 1,000 (actual number TBD), but instead I get the 8 results with the last_used date, without any of the NULL dates.

Here's a sample of the expected results:

### item                last_used

21050000202-0       2017-08-31 00:00:00.000
2200130425          2017-08-09 00:00:00.000
2200130494          2017-09-15 00:00:00.000
220030010           2017-09-25 00:00:00.000
2201050937-2        2017-09-01 00:00:00.000
22081001202         2017-08-16 00:00:00.000
2209070909          2017-08-15 11:31:45.230
221500              2017-08-21 00:00:00.000
21010000215         NULL
21050000215         NULL
21050000215-0       NULL
210800              NULL
21330000202         NULL
213600              NULL
22000000210         NULL

Comment: Please provide some sample data, actual results and expected results, ideally in table variable form or dbfiddle to allow people to copy and paste the SQL.

Comment: Does m.trans_date contain NULL values?

Comment: @Piotr m.trans_date does not have null dates, if i.item hasn't transacted as m.item in m.matltran_mst then then entire item wouldn't have a trans_date, so I thought LEFT JOIN would provide me with NULL results.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, how would I edit to include data in table form? (I'm a SO rookie, sorry!)

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom LSH under the question. And then see my answer that follows for how to setup the data and query https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012771/1127428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a function such as MAX on a column, any rows with NULL values in that column will be ignored.  You might be able to get what you want if you split out the query for rows WITH NULL m.trans_date from the query for rows NOT BETWEEN certain dates in a UNION query:

```
SELECT 
i.item
, i.description
--, i.last_inv
--, i.change_date
, 1 AS 'last_used'
FROM item_mst i
LEFT JOIN matltran_mst m on m.item = i.item
WHERE m.trans_date IS NULL
GROUP BY i.item, i.description
ORDER BY 'last_used'

UNION

SELECT 
i.item
, i.description
--, i.last_inv
--, i.change_date
, MAX(m.trans_date)AS 'last_used'
FROM item_mst i
LEFT JOIN matltran_mst m on m.item = i.item
WHERE i.item like '2%' and m.trans_type <> 'M'   
GROUP BY i.item, i.description
HAVING (MAX(m.trans_date) NOT BETWEEN '10/1/2017' and '5/8/2019') 
ORDER BY 'last_used'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move "m.trans_type <> 'M' " from WHERE clause to ON clause.

"m.trans_type <> 'M'" is causing this statement to behave like inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for *all* dates being `NULL` rather than one of them.  So, try this:

```
HAVING MAX(m.trans_date) NOT BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2019-05-08' OR
 -- or whatever these dates really are
       COUNT(m.trans_date) < COUNT(*)  -- are any of them NULL?
```

You can also fix the rest of the query:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(m.trans_date) = COUNT(*) THEN MAX(m.trans_dte) END) as last_used  -- NULL if any are NULL
FROM item_mst i LEFT JOIN
     matltran_mst m 
     ON m.item = i.item AND and m.trans_type <> 'M' 
WHERE i.item like '2%'   
GROUP BY i.item, i.description
HAVING MAX(m.trans_date) NOT BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2019-05-08' OR
     -- or whatever these dates really are
       COUNT(m.trans_date) < COUNT(*)  -- are any of them NULL?
ORDER BY last_used;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly use ignoring so many CASE/WHEN-

```
MAX(m.trans_date) END AS 'last_used'
```

This will directly return Maximum data (If dates available) or NULL (If no date available). And please change ORDER BY as below-

```
ORDER BY MAX(m.trans_date)
```